# Server Object Creation Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic, runtime-error, runtimeexception

I am unable to run a particular ASP page in my website. It is throwing the below error.

> Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'
>
> Server.CreateObject Failed
>
> /includes/conferenceRoom/init.asp, line 13
>
> 800401f3.

However my page is running well in Prod server but it is throwing error in my dev derver. I am unable to find the root cause for this error.

The line 13 is to create obj for my calender app in ASP:

```
set objCal= server.CreateObject("bsCal.cDate")
```

Any one please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a COM component on your dev server if you have all the components to hand have you use `regsvr32` to register them? Can you post exactly what component (classid) at line 13 `CreateObject` is failing on?

Comment: Can you please provide the line of code in that init.asp file at line 13? Without knowing what component you are trying to create an instance of, we won't be able to help. It could be a 3rd party component missing from your dev server, or a core component that's not working properly/missing.

Comment: There are three common issues with COM components. First, as Lankymart suggests your component may be missing or unregistered.  Second, the IUSR account on your dev server may not have permission to access the COM object dll.  Third, it may be a 32 bit component and you haven't enabled 32 bit applications in your app pool.  If we knew what the component was then we'd have a better idea

Comment: The line 13 is to create obj for my calender app in ASP set objCal= server.CreateObject("bsCal.cDate")

Any one please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: @AzhaguLakshmanaKumar you need to copy the DLL file from prod server to your machine then use regsvr32 to register it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the COM object (i.e. bsCal.cDate) is registered. Find its DLL and register it using regsvr32

Assuming you copied your dll to the folder d:\objects.
In a command prompt type:

> regsvr32 d:\objects\YourDll.dll